# How to turn on privacy VPN configurations in info.plist

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a app that will be filter all network traffics from Iphone or Ipad. 
I looked into `info.plist` but I don't know what setting I have to choice.
My expected something like this.

[image]

This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import NetworkExtension

@objc(TestingProxy)
class TestingProxy: NSObject {
  let vpnManager = NEVPNManager.shared();

  private var vpnLoadHandler: (Error?) -> Void {
    return { (error:Error?) in
      if ((error) != nil) {
        print("Could not load VPN Configurations")
        return;
      }
      let p = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()
      p.username = "SOME_USERNAME"
      p.serverAddress = "example.com"
      p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.sharedSecret

      let kcs = KeychainService();
      kcs.save(key: "SHARED", value: "MY_SHARED_KEY")
      kcs.save(key: "VPN_PASSWORD", value: "MY_PASSWORD")

      p.sharedSecretReference = kcs.load(key: "SHARED")
      p.passwordReference = kcs.load(key: "VPN_PASSWORD")
      p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
      p.disconnectOnSleep = false

      self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = p
      self.vpnManager.localizedDescription = "Contensi"
      self.vpnManager.isEnabled = true
      self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: self.vpnSaveHandler)
    }
  }

  private var vpnSaveHandler: (Error?) -> Void {
    return { (error:Error?) in
      if (error != nil) {
        print("Could not save VPN Configurations")
        return
      } else {
        do {
          try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error starting VPN Connection \(error.localizedDescription)");
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. Something like this, but I don't have Development account so I could not confirm that for now.

Go to **Xcode -> Project -> Targets -> Capabilities** and Enable VPN and Enable Network